# Upon installing package my vignettes folder is removed for being empty?

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, r-package, bibtex

I won't be able to provide my package as it's in a private repo.
But basically

1. I used the `usethis::use_article()` function to create a vignettes folder
2. Dragged an RMD file and bibtex file into the articles folder, committed the changes and pushed it to github.
3. After installing my package this message is produced
   [image]

Does anyone know why this issue would occur? On my github repo the files are definitely there so I'm not sure what the issue could be.
[image]
EDIT: I noticed the same removed empty directory message appears during `devtools::check()` as well.